# Figure out domain and range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a hard and fast way, step by step process to figure out domain and range? I don't know where to start and lack the insight to just know what it can and can't be.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any certain function in your mind?

Answer (score 2):

The domain $A$ and the codomain $B$ are inherent parts of a function $f: A \to B$, so they can just be read off the definition of $f$.

Maybe your question is about how to extract domain and range from the *graph* of $f : A\to B$, which is the subset $G = \{(a,f(a)) \mid a\in A\}$ of $A\times B$.
The domain $A$ can be recovered from the graph as
$$\{a \mid \exists b : (a,b)\in G\}.$$
For the range, it depends what you are referring to:
There is no way to recover the codomain $B$ from the graph.
The image of the function is given by
$$\operatorname{im}(f) = \{f(a) \mid a\in A\} = \{b \mid \exists a : (a,b)\in G\}.$$